# Select one random index per unique element in NumPy array and account for missing ones from reference array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, image-processing, array-broadcasting

If I have the following

```
import numpy as np

mid_img = np.array([[0, 0, 1],
                    [2, 0, 2],
                    [3, 1, 0]])

values = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])              

locations = np.full((len(values), 2), [-1, -1])
locations[np.argwhere(mid_img == values)] = mid_img  # this of course doesn't work, but hopefully shows intent
```

'locations' would look something like this (showing only as intermediate step for explanation.  Getting this output is not required.

```
[[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2]],  #ie, locations matching values[0]
 [[0, 2], [2, 1]],                  #ie, locations matching values[1]
 [[1, 0], [1, 2]],                  #ie, locations matching values[2]
 [[2, 0]]]                          #ie, locations matching values[3]
 [[-1, -1]]]                        #ie, values[4] not found
```

The final output would then randomly select location for each value row:

```
print locations
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1],
 [2, 1],
 [1, 0],
 [2, 0],
 [-1, -1]
```

Here is a looped version of the process:

```
for row_index in np.arange(0, len(values)):
    found_indices = np.argwhere(mid_img == row_index)
    try:
        locations[row_index] = found_indices[np.random.randint(len(found_indices))]
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Can we assume `values` to be all the unique values in `mid_img`? Also, can we assume `mid_img` to have only positive values?

Comment: Oh, good questions.  mid_img will only be 0-255 int (so always positive) and values will always be populated with unique ints (no duplicates)

Comment: So, that `4` in `values` seems like odd one.

Comment: the goal there was to show that if a value is not found it, should stay some arbitrary non-positive value (ie -1, -1)

Comment: Could there be some unique element from `mid_img` not present in `values` - Something like : `values = np.array([0, 1, 3, 4]) ` (2 is missing)?

Comment: any/all element(s) in `mid_img` will exist in `values`

Comment: in fact, now that I think about, I don't know if it will simplify this problem, but we can say that `values` will always be a sequential list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one vectorized way -

```
# Get flattened sort indices for input array
idx = mid_img.ravel().argsort()

# Get counts for all uniqe elements
c = np.bincount(mid_img.flat)
c = c[c>0]

# Get bins to be used with searchsorted later on so that we select 
# exactly one unique index per group. These would be linear indices
bins = np.repeat(1.0/c,c).cumsum()
n = len(c)
sidx = np.searchsorted(bins,np.random.rand(n)+np.arange(n))
out_lidx = idx[sidx]

# Convert to row-col index format
row,col = np.unravel_index(out_lidx, mid_img.shape)

# Initialize output array
locations = np.full((len(values), 2), [-1, -1])

# Get valid ones based on values and indexed output
valid = values <= mid_img[row[-1],col[-1]]

# Finally assign row, col indices into final output
locations[valid,0] = row
locations[valid,1] = col
```

Comment: Thanks Divakar!  As usual, your solutions are always super helpful.